# ¿Cómo ponerle un fondo de un color a una imagen con open cv en Python?

Tags: python, imagen, opencv, inteligencia-artificial, cv2

Tengo una imagen en blanco y negro, pero quiero que el fondo sea de un color grisáceo, pero no logro encontrar como puedo hacer que los píxeles que en mi imagen son negros pasen a ser grises, esta es la imagen en cuestión:

[image]

y este es el código que estoy usando para tratar dicha imagen:

```
img = cv2.imread('{}/{}'.format(base_dir, file))
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 
gray_mod = cv2.addWeighted(gray, 50, np.zeros_like(gray), 0, 80)

kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.float32) / 42

dst = cv2.filter2D(gray_mod,-1,kernel)
dst = cv2.resize(dst, (28 * 5, 28* 5))

cv2.imshow('gray mask', dst)
```

el resultado que he obtenido es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no logro hacer que el fondo sea entero de color gris, pensé que con el addWeighted funcionaría pero no se como hacer que la segunda imagen se vea sobre un fondo distinto, por ejemplo, gris, si alguien sabe como podría hacerlo se lo agradecería, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con imágenes en Blanco y negro claramente diferenciadas, se puede hacer sin OpenCV. Tienes que seleccionar aquellos valores del array cercanos al negro y ponerlos en gris. Por ejemplo así:

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

(X, y),(_, _)  = mnist.load_data()

img = X[1].copy()

seleccionar_valores_a_cambiar = 140
tono_gris = 160

img[img < seleccionar_valores_a_cambiar] = tono_gris
plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
```

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes jugar con las variables `seleccionar_valores_a_cambiar` y `tono_gris` hasta conseguir el tono de gris que quieras.

### Conclusión

**Una imágen es una matriz de números**, si tienes una imagen en la que todos los valores son negros (es decir cero o cercanos a cero) y el resto de valores son blancos (es decir 254 o cercanos a 254) solo tienes que seleccionar un umbral para cambiar el tono de los valores blancos o negros.